# Liquibase - permissions issue when creating log and lock tables

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I am adding Liquibase support to the existing project. When I ran `changelog-sync-sql` operation, all SQL queries were generated correctly. I checked them and wanted to execute. So, I tried to run `changelog-sync`, however it failed due to insufficient permissions, i.e.:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
 [Failed SQL: (1031) CREATE TABLE <schema>.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK ...
```

I copied the entire create table query and logged in to the db using exactly the same jdbc connection string, username, password and schema and I managed to execute it manually without any errors. So, looks like the user has all the required permissions.

Liquibase version: 4.23.0. Database vendor: Oracle.

Is that some kind of a bug? How can I investigate it?

I tried to debug it with FINE level and I see that Liquibase goes with 10 retries of that query and eventually fails.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the JDBC Driver? If so which version? Is this a standalone Java program or Spring Boot (if you can share the code snippet it would be good).